# performing piping manually in c

Tags: c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing my own shell… stuck on pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461331/writing-my-own-shell-stuck-on-pipes)

I'm building a program with shell like functionality, and I was wondering how to perform a piping operation. So when the system executes `program1 arg | tee output-file` the system will connect the `stdin` from the `tee` to the `stdout` from `program1` as well as catching any `stderr` and the final `stdout`.

Comment: it is, but is it going to be similar to c++ on unix, but I don't really see how to perform the piping operation in that question.

Comment: The code in the answers there should work fine as both C and C++, and on any Unixlike, including Linux, BSD, Mac OS, Solaris...

Comment: @bdonlan righto, im not sure how his function would be used within the rest of the program, would it run through the request string and split at the `|` points then run 1 in to 2, then 2 into 3 (if there were more than 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for a pipe:

```
int p[2];
pipe(p);
```

Before the `exec()` of the first program, bind its standard output to it, and close the other fds:

```
dup2(p[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(p[0]);
close(p[1]);
```

Before the `exec()` of the second program redirect its standard input:

```
dup2(p[1], STDIN_FILENO);
close(p[0]);
close(p[1]);
```

You will also have to close both ends of the pipe in the master program after the `fork()`s, and you are done (for the pipe setup).

Comment: One of the most common mistakes with piping is not closing enough file descriptors.  This code avoids that problem.