# How to keep my shell running after a command

Tags: c++

I am running this basic shell program in another shell. I am unable to figure out why my shell doesn't keep running after "ls" executes. I dont have an exit for it but it goes back to original shell. I have to run my shell program every time if want to use it. i figured thats what the fork() is supposed to do.  I only want my shell to exit using the exit command which i coded with the if else statement. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Oh and disregard the gettoks() parser function, i couldn't figure out how to use it for input so i wrote if else statements for the string input cmSTR rather then using the gettoks() parser. Mainly because i couldn't figure how to pass the input into it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;
// Initializing counters for trapping
static int cc_counter = 0;
static int cz_counter = 0;
static int cq_counter = 0;
//Functions for trap signal handler
void cc_handler( int signo )
{
++cc_counter;
}
void cz_handler( int signo )
{
++cz_counter;
}
void cq_handler( int signo )
{
++cq_counter;
}

//*********************************************************
//
// Extern Declarations
//
//*********************************************************
using namespace std;
extern "C"
{
extern char **gettoks();
} 


//*********************************************************
//
// Main Function
//
//*********************************************************
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
// local variables
int ii;
char **toks;
int retval;

// initialize local variables
ii = 0;
toks = NULL;
retval = 0;
char buf[1000];//Initialize of size for current working directory
string cmSTR;//String to hold input
int status;//Initialization of status for fork()
pid_t pid;//Declaration of pid

// main (infinite) loop
while( true )
{
    signal( SIGINT, cc_handler );// Traps Ctrl+C
    signal( SIGTSTP, cz_handler);// Traps Ctrl+Z
    signal( SIGQUIT, cq_handler);// Traps Ctrl+\
  //prompt and show current working directory
  cout <<("RS_SHELL:") << getcwd(buf,1000) << "\t";
  getline(cin ,cmSTR);//read input from keyboard
  // if else loop to switch based on command input
  if(cmSTR == "ls")// if ls, then execute arguement
  {
    execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", NULL );//System call to execute ls

    }
    else if(cmSTR == "exit")//if exit, then execute block of code
    {
        cout << "Ctrl C entered: " << ++cc_counter << "times"<< endl;
        cout << "Ctrl Z entered: " << ++cz_counter << "times"<< endl;
        cout << "Ctrl Back Slash entered: " << ++cq_counter << "times"<< endl;
        exit(1);
        }
    else if(cmSTR == "guish")// if guish, execute guish shell
    {
        execvp("guish", NULL);
        }
        //if input is not any of previous commands then fork()
    else if(cmSTR != "ls" && cmSTR != "exit" && cmSTR != "guish" && cmSTR != "\n")
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)//Loop to fork parent and child process
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
            exit(-1);
            }
            else if (pid == 0)//Child process
        {
            execvp("guish", NULL);//system call to execute guish shell

            }
            else //Parent process
            {
                waitpid( -1, &status,0);
                exit(0);
                }
                }




  // get arguments
  toks = gettoks();

  if( toks[0] != NULL )
{
  // simple loop to echo all arguments
  for( ii=0; toks[ii] != NULL; ii++ )
    {
      cout << "Argument " << ii << ": " << toks[ii] << endl;
    }

  if( !strcmp( toks[0], "exit" ))
    break;
 }
    }

   // return to calling environment
   return( retval );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, `execl` and its related functions overlay the current process with a new process. Thus, after the `execl` call that starts `ls`, your program won't exist any more to keep running.

If you want your shell program to stay around after running `ls`, you'll need to `fork()` *before* the call `execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", NULL );`.

Also, if you want the output from `ls` to appear in the same console as your shell, as I think you might be intending, you will need to pipe the output from `ls` back to your shell and then write that output onto your shell's console. See [Writing my own shell… stuck on pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461331/writing-my-own-shell-stuck-on-pipes?rq=1), for instance.

Comment: outside of the if statement?

Comment: Yes, I would be inclined to `fork()` before the `if` rather than forking for each of the `if` cases individually - DRY (don't repeat yourself) is a good motto.