# How to run a bash commands in C++ without using system in linux

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I want to take an input, a bash command, and be able to execute that input from my CPP program. This is for school and we are not allowed to use "system" so I do not know any other way to do this. Also, the program can take up to 3 commands via pipe. I've looked up how to do this but it just gets more confusing. If there are any resources or a question similar to this that has been answered please link. Thanks.

Comment: There's a whole family of `exec` functions you can use.

Comment: [This](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: Won't work for intrinsic bash commands of course, only executables. But you can also run bash directly using `execxy()` and pass commands via a pipe for example.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209206/1851678) answer your question? It uses the example of executing `echo` from the program.

Comment: I apologize: I marked the wrong question as duplicate.  But there are *many* questions on SO that can answer this.  eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094063/fork-pipe-and-exec-process-creation-and-communication

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461331/writing-my-own-shell-stuck-on-pipes) is a similar question.

Basically, for the shell part, you are going to use `fork` and some form of `exec` (e.g., `execve`) to get that to execute.

For pipes, you're going to have to use the `pipe` command in C++, which will allow you to write and read from the pipe from separate children (in your case, up to two pipes, so you can create a 2x2 array of file descriptors, as a normal pipe is just a 2 element array). You should write the output of one program into the correct pipe and read it from the pipe in the next child once the first terminates.